# Pandas not selecting columns based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
id   device
814  desktop
814  mobile
236  mobile
498  desktop
348  mobile
287  mobile
287  desktop
```

I want to query the `id's` where device is both `mobile & desktop`

```
df.loc[(df['device'] == 'mobile') & (df['device'] == 'desktop'), ['id','device']]
```

The output should be

```
id  device
814 desktop
814 mobile
287 desktop
287 mobile
```

Instead I just get an empty dataframe

```
id device
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&` operator is used to specify multiple conditions, each of which must be `True`. Therefore, the mask `(s == 'mobile') & (s == 'desktop')` for a given series `s` will always return an empty dataframe.

Instead, you can group `device` to `set` for each `id`. Then use `set.issubset`, or equivalent syntactic sugar `<=`:

```
g = df.groupby('id')['device'].apply(set)
search = {'mobile', 'desktop'}

res = df[search <= df['id'].map(g)]

print(res)

    id   device
0  814  desktop
1  814   mobile
5  287   mobile
6  287  desktop
```

Comment: Beautiful `<=` ;)

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much for the explanation as well I totally forgot that both condition must be `True`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use set intersection

```
cond1 = df[df.device == 'desktop'].id.values
cond2 = df[df.device == 'mobile'].id.values
set(cond1) & set(cond2)
```

gives

```
{287, 814}
```

Then

```
df.loc[df.id.isin(x)]

    id  device
0   814 desktop
1   814 mobile
5   287 mobile
6   287 desktop
```